# How do you route [OPTIONS] in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, activerecord, routes

I am making a REST service in Rails.  Here are my routes.

```
  resources :users
  match '/users', :controller => 'users', :action => 'options', :constraints => {:method => 'OPTIONS'}
```

I am able to [GET] my users.  I am trying to update my users and I get an error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/users/1"):
```

When I run `rake routes` here are the routes that I am given:

```
    users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
                 /users(.:format)          users#options {:method=>"OPTIONS"}
```

Could someone please show me how to fix my routes so I can make any kind of REST call?  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

```
match '/users' => "users#options", via: :options
```

would also be a possible route if placed before the other routes.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to create two additional routes for `/users` and for `/users/id` you can do this:

```
match 'users(/:id)' => 'users#options', via: [:options]
```

In this case, the `id` become optional, both `/users` and `/users/id` will respond to the same route.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that I could not route the request, was that my `match` did not have the user id in it.  I added the line:

```
match '/users/:id', :controller => 'users', :action => 'options', :constraints => {:method => 'OPTIONS'}
```

and now I can route all of my GET request.

Answer (score 1):

If you met this problem using javascript's ajax call, you maybe meet the cross-site problem. (e.g. your browser's current url is : `http://a.xx.com` and the ajax send a request to `http://b.xx.com` ) , then Rails / other-backend-server will get this kind of `OPTIONS` request.

To avoid this, besides changing your `ruby` code, I suggest you do one of these two solutions:

1. add CORS support using: https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors, lines of code just work.
2. send all the request to `a.xx.com`, then change your Nginx's config, redirect these requests to `b.xx.com`.

By the way, I don't suggest you change your `routes.rb` file to support OPTIONS request. This will mess your code up.

refer to: [AXIOS request method changes to 'OPTIONS' instead of 'GET'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63752007/axios-request-method-changes-to-options-instead-of-get)