# How can I route unmatched OPTION requests in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My servers are being hit by sporadic OPTIONS requests to my root path. These are all bots trying to find vulnerabilities. I want to return a `404 not found` instead of raising an error, since my error tracking service is being hit all the time.

I have tried using:

```
options '/', to: 'application#return_not_found'
```

to route these requests properly, but Rails 5 gives me an error.

Comment: what error Rails gives?

Comment: The error is: `undefined method 'options' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007f8ee2b57a20> (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540065/how-do-you-route-options-in-rails), you can use:

`match '/' => 'application#return_not_found', via: :options`