# axios GET request changes to Options request - status 401 Unauthorized- Postman works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js, preflight

I'm aware of the whole " preflight request " story... and my server does support options request.

What bothers me is that I tried every single online API testing {Postmamn,reqbin...} and it works just fine but when I use simple axios code or fetch I get the options request with status of 401 Unauthorized!

**Localhost env runs on [localtunnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel) & i'm using next.js default server configuration**

**Added nginx to the server from https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html**

/example.com/conf/nginx/cors.conf

**Axios code**

```
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Access-Token", "token-here");

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'get',
        headers: myHeaders,
        crossDomain: true,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("https://example.com/x/wp-json/api", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

**Console error**

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/xx/wp-json/x/api. (Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed). Status code: 401.
```

```
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000’)
```

| Server has the following headers |
| --- |
| access-control-allow-credentials:true |
| access-control-allow-headers: Authorization, X-WP-Nonce, Content-Disposition, Content-MD5, Content-Type |
| access-control-allow-methods: **OPTIONS**, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE |
| access-control-allow-origin: https://localtunnel-URL.loca.lt |
| content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 |

[image]

[AXIOS request method changes to 'OPTIONS' instead of 'GET'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63752007/axios-request-method-changes-to-options-instead-of-get)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm aware of the whole " preflight request " story... and my server does support options request.

Your server is requiring a authorization before allowing access to the OPTIONS response.

Essentially the conversation goes something like this:

---

Browser: May I make a request that includes my credentials?

Server: Since you didn't include your credentials when asking for permission to include your credentials, you cannot have permission to include your credentials.

---

You need to exclude OPTIONS requests from authn/authz.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about your server-side code. Try asking a new question about how to change it. Include a [mcve]. Include suitable tags. Since the URL includes WP I would guess that you'd be asking a [tag:wordpress] question, so I wouldn't be answering it, but someone who knows something about that topic might.

Comment: Server side code is PHP/WordPress nginx

Comment: And why I don't see that error when I use Postman or any other API testing tool

Comment: See the section "Why the Same Origin Policy only applies to JavaScript in a web page" in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068

Comment: I've not found anything o how to exclude Options requests from authn/authz in wordpress

Comment: Then ask a question about it as I suggested.