# DELETE request work from Postman but not from frontend or browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, axios, fetch-api

I have built a simple ASP .NET Framework MVC app. GET and POST work fine.. however when i try to make a DELETE request it works from Postman, but from my frontend(React & Axios) I get err 404. From browser (chrome/edge) i get err 404.
I think it's worth noting that this is my first backend. Ever.
I've lost like 5 hours over it now.

This is my controller code:

```
// DELETE: Homes/Delete/5
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<HomeEntity> Delete(int id) {
  return await homesManager.DeleteAsync(id);
}
```

This is my manager code:

```
public async Task<HomeEntity> DeleteAsync ( int id) {
  HomeEntity homeModel = db.Homes.Find(id);
  db.Homes.Remove(homeModel);
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();
  return homeModel;
}
```

This is my routeConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig {
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

This is my delete request from frontend:

```
const handlePropertyDelete = async () => {
  try {
    axios
      .delete(`https://localhost:44333/Homes/Delete/${property.id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Property deleted:", response.data);
    
        // Handle success
        //Close the delete dialog
        onClose();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error deleting property:", error);
        console.error("Error status:", error.response?.status);
        console.error("Error data:", error.response?.data);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
};
```

And the errors:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAduD.png)

help please, i've never felt so stuck...

I tried multiple formats of the axios request, fetch request, making the request on different browsers. I dont understand why DELETE won't work when POST and GET do. And DELETE works on Postman from the same URL so it must be my delete function

Comment: You are not getting the 404 for the DELETE request. Browsers send an `OPTIONS` request before sending the actual request. You are getting the 404 there.

See how to handle `OPTIONS` requests with your framework.

Comment: Any idea how could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the right url "Home" instead of "Homes"

```
`https://localhost:44333/Home/Delete/${property.id}`
```

if it is still not working , then try to remove [HttpDelete] from the action

Answer (score -1):

I didn't use `axios` before, but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63752007/axios-request-method-changes-to-options-instead-of-get) maybe can help you

and maybe you can try to use `HttpClient` for that, then like below

```
http.delete(`https://localhost:44333/Homes/Delete/${property.id}`)
```