# Why does Axios.get(URL) not return consistently?

Tags: reactjs, axios, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api, django-channels

I am having trouble understanding why an `axios.get(...url...)` request does not always return a result to the frontend.

The code that does not work consistently (returns a result every other request on average) is as follows:

```
async function subscribeToAnalysis (analysisId) {

    await axios.get(/localhost:8000/someEndpoint/), {
        timeout: 50000,
    })
    .then(async response => {
        console.log("Response", response);
        // Do more stuff with response and recall the function to subscribe again
    };
}
```

However, if I swap out the `axios.get(...)` for a `fetch(...)` request, it works as expected and a result is returned every time as expected.

```
async function subscribeToAnalysis (analysisId) {

    await fetch(/localhost:8000/someEndpoint/))
    .then(async response => {
        console.log("Response", response);
        // Do more stuff with response and recall the function to subscribe again
    };
}
```

The `axios.get(...)` requests work fine in the backend when sending back Django Rest `Response` objects or `HttpResponse` objects. In my use-case, I am using Django Channels, so I have to explicitly send headers and then the content.

For example, I send headers via:

```
await self.send_headers(headers=[
            (b"Content-type", b"application/json"),
            (b"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", b"*"),
            (b"Allow", b"GET"),
            (b"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", b"true"),
            (b"Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", b"same-origin"),
            (b"Referrer-Policy", b"same-origin"),
            (b"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", b"Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept, Authorization"),])
```

Then later, send the content for the subscribing request via:

```
await self.send_body(bytes(json.dumps(analysisData), 'utf-8'))
```

This same code works fine with the `fetch()` requests but not with the `axios.get()` requests and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR; `GET` requests send an `OPTIONS` method request prior to the `GET` to get information.

Since this question, I have instead gone an alternative route of using `fetch` versus `Axios` for requests. While debugging another issue with the task, we stumbled across that the `fetch` request was actually sending an `OPTIONS` method request prior to the `GET` request got sent.

Looking up if this may happen with Axios, as well, it seems that it does (and has since been confirmed via testing). See [AXIOS request method changes to 'OPTIONS' instead of 'GET'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63752007/axios-request-method-changes-to-options-instead-of-get) for more information.